# c read block of lines and store them

Tags: c, bash, fgets

I need a c program that does the following:
- read a block of lines in a file
- store them temporaly
- extract a specific column from that block and store that
- goes on to the next block

In bash it looks like that:

```
counter=126
while [ $counter -lt 1344 ]; #1344 because the file has 1344 lines
do
    head -n $counter best.sim.simulate > temp1 #read the first 126 lines
    blabla #do something with temp1
    Unc=$(grep PX temp2 | awk '{print $5}') #extract column 5 of first 126 lines
    span=$(grep span temp2 | awk '{print $8}') #extract column 8 of first 126 lines
    echo $span $Unc >> results #store the columns
    let counter=counter+122 #extend the block
done
```

In c my attempts looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
FILE *filepointer;
char string[100];
filepointer=fopen("best.sim.simulate", "r"); 
while (fgets(string, sizeof(string), filepointer) != NULL) {
    printf("%s",string); /* print the string */
    }
fclose(filepointer); /* close the file */
return 0;
}
```

What do I have to do to get the c code doing the same as the bash code?
By the way: I need the c program because this snippet of code is part of a larger loop that that runs over several hours. And in c the loop runs faster as in bash.

**edit**
the file looks like this

```
fake.rf 1440.00000000 61277.45134800286753318 1.20000 7 
fake.rf 1440.00000000 61283.88791346459694154 1.20000 7 
fake.rf 1440.00000000 61289.34046454497647005 1.20000 7 
fake.rf 1440.00000000 61296.15558287300736495 1.20000 7 
fake.rf 1440.00000000 61302.19514871358752472 1.20000 7 
fake.rf 1440.00000000 61307.28928664621331635 1.20000 7
and so on
```

Comment: Many problems with the code, for example you don't check that `fopen()` succeeded. And you need to post the content of the file.

Comment: fake.rf 1440.00000000 61277.45134800286753318 1.20000 7 
 fake.rf 1440.00000000 61283.88791346459694154 1.20000 7 
 fake.rf 1440.00000000 61289.34046454497647005 1.20000 7 
 fake.rf 1440.00000000 61296.15558287300736495 1.20000 7 
 fake.rf 1440.00000000 61302.19514871358752472 1.20000 7 
 fake.rf 1440.00000000 61307.28928664621331635 1.20000 7

Comment: check the answers in the post I marked this as a duplicate of, there you will find what you need, it's very hard to imitate `awk` with c code, but the answers there are clean and simple.

Comment: okay, thanks. I will have a look

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. There are too many c-terms I don't know and I can't reduce the code which is written there down to my problem. Can you clearify what I need from the linked page?

Comment: You need to tokenize each line as is done in the ansers at the link.